# Ghost field in Odoo?

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-12

I have a field on a folio custom addon which is called "Discount". When I hover the mouse on the field it says me the type and the object but when I go at that object I can't find it. Also when editing the xml file from my IDE it won't update no matter how many rests and upgrades I will make to it. When I edit it from interactive debug it works(i.e. I can make it disappear by commenting the line and appear again by un-commenting). Can someone tell me what's the cause?

This is the code where the field points to:
[link1](https://pastecode.io/s/ufp6guxq) [link2](https://pastecode.io/s/8a60hcr1) [xml](https://pastecode.io/s/b3n0kztf)

Image [here](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/761612693374238735/964251839203774554/Screenshot_from_2022-04-14_21-51-22.png?width=863&height=660).

Comment: Make sure you have the module folder not duplicated in different addons folders, Check all your addons paths and make sure the module is not duplicated.

Comment: @WaleedMohsen thanks for your comment. I checked it I didn't have any duplicated models. Reinstalled and the same issue.

Comment: Another thing to check, You said when you hover the mouse you get the object of field discount so you can activate developer mode and go to settings then technical then models, search for the object and open it and find the field discount, click on it, pop up window will be open go to ```Miscellaneous``` tab and find the module name in field ```In Apps```. Let me know the result

Comment: @WaleedMohsen fosho, I will update in upcoming hours!